# Set Email Priority with SendGrid API

Tags: email, azure, sendgrid

Im using the SendGrid API in my Windows Azure environment to send emails.  I have a need to alter the email priority (Low\High Importance) of some emails, but I don't see any properties that allow me to do this.

Does anyone have experience with SendGrid who knows how to change the priority?  There is a property that allows me to add headers.. so Im not sure if that's something I can use to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the Web API you can use the [headers](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html#-send) parameter as you mention. If sending via SMTP you can just add the headers to your message.

There are a few headers defined in RFC 4021 that support this as well as some custom ones. I'd use the following JSON for the headers parameter to start:

`{“Priority”: “Urgent”, “Importance”: “high”}`

If that doesn't work you can also look into the `X-Priority` and `X-MSMail-Priority` headers.

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick, but I had to use some slightly different headers.  I didn't use Priority, I used Importance as high and X-Priority as 1, and Importance as low and X-Priority as 5 to send a low importance message.  Thx!

Answer (score 6):

I was also looking for a way to mark email as important. After going through a couple of articles, I found the answer over here-
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/251

All you need to do is add priority in your mail headers. Like this-

```
mailMessage.Headers.Add("Priority", "Urgent");
mailMessage.Headers.Add("Importance", "high");
```

Code above works for high priority. I am guessing you would have to do something similar for low priority emails. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I found that using `Headers.Add` would throw an **Object reference not set to instance of an object error**.

Use `mailMessage.AddHeader` to avoid this.

Found on the same link Pallavi provided.
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/251

Answer (score 2):

Based on my tests, `SmtpClient` sets the following headers for high priority:

```
"X-Priority", "1"
"Priority", "urgent"
"Importance", "high"
```

And for low priority:

```
"X-Priority", "5"
"Priority", "non-urgent"
"Importance", "low"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the SendGrid API (v9.29.2), I had to add the headers like so:

### Low

```
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new()
{
    { "Importance", "Low" },
    { "X-Priority", "5" }
};

mailMessage.Headers = headers;
```

### High

```
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new()
{
    { "Importance", "High" },
    { "X-Priority", "1" }
};

mailMessage.Headers = headers;
```

When I used `mailMessage.AddHeader`, it did not add the headers and it did not throw an exception.